# How do I get the Windows 10 installer to boot from the right partition?

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, windows-11, windows-installation

I'm trying to set up a USB drive to boot multiple OSes using vanilla GRUB. I'd like for it to be able to boot the installer for both Windows 10 and Windows 11. The way I'm trying to do this is by creating an EFI system partition for GRUB as well as two NTFS partitions, one containing the windows 10 installer and one containing the windows 11 installer:

```
sda             8:0    1  28.9G  0 disk  
├─sda1          8:1    1  12.9G  0 part  -- ESP
├─sda2          8:2    1     8G  0 part  -- win10
└─sda3          8:3    1     8G  0 part  -- win11
```

The GRUB configuration snippet that is responsible for creating the Windows menuentries looks like this:

```
for os in win10 win11; do
    if search --label $os; then
        menuentry $os {
            insmod chain
            search --no-floppy --set=root --label $os
            chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
        }
    fi
done
```

And this does work to boot the Windows installer... kind of. The problem I'm having is that regardless of which one I choose, they both boot into the Windows 11 installer. I suspect that the Windows bootloader searches for its partition on disk instead of using the one it's located on, and they're both finding the Windows 11 partition.

I tried booting into the installer and modifying the bootloader options using `bcdedit`, but it gave the error

```
The set system store device command has failed.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

[image: bcdedit being bad]

I tried this with both the Windows 10 and the Windows 11 partitions.

Are there any other ways to convince the Windows bootloader to choose a different partition?